# IIR with asymptotic impulse response

Tags: infinite-impulse-response

I have plot some of the IIR filter's impulse responses and some of them are exponentially increasing, increasing, decreasing etc but some IIR's impulse response approaches 0. If for example I have an IIR filter defined by its lccde:

$$ 6 y[n] + y[n-1] - 2y[n-2] = x[n] - 2x[n-1] $$

or

$$ y[n] = \frac{1}{6}x[n] - \frac{1}{3}x[n-1] - \frac{1}{6}y[n-1] + \frac{1}{3}y[n-2] $$

when I plot its impulse response in matlab:

```
[h,n] = impz([1 -2],[6 1 -2]);
stem(n,h);
```

its impulse response would approach 0, and this zero value will bestarting at n = 23. Does this mean that the IIR is an FIR since I can cut off the impulse response at n = 23?

Comment: $y[23]$ is really zero?  or just very tiny?

Comment: Plot the amplitude on a log scale

Comment: Wait so this lccde does not approach 0? how do I plot this properly/

Comment: It's an IIR. **infinite** impulse response, as explained in comments and answers to your two other questions, already ([1](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35903/approximating-an-iir-filter-to-a-fir), [2](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35857/dft-in-iir-filters)). you must stop tackling IIRs with the tools only applicable to FIRs!

Comment: @LeBlancLord: plot(20*log10(h));

Comment: @MarcusMüller, just because the sequence generating equation is recursive does not mean the filter has an infinite impulse response. Often IIR and FIR are used as synonyms for recursive and non-recursive, but that's not accurate. FIR filters can be recursive, and that's not just some fringe case.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac won't argue with you about the common confusion about (non)recursive/(in)finite IR –point is that OP has two questions on this :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, i am not sure that Jazz meant a non-recursive IIR (this is not that), but perhaps what we call a Truncated IIR (TIIR) which is a recursive FIR (moving sum or moving average is the most common example) with pole/zero cancellation.  this also is not that.  it's just an ordinary IIR.

Answer (score 1):

As per the exact solution of a [discrete LTI system](http://wolfweb.unr.edu/~fadali/ee472/DTState-Space.pdf):

$$y(t)=C A^k x_0+C\sum_{k=0}^{t-1}A^{t-k-1} B u(k)+D u(t)$$

and considering that $u(t)=\delta(t)$ and $x_0=0$ for the impulse response, we have:

$$h(t)=C A^{t-1} B+D \delta(t)$$

where $A$,$B$,$C$ and $D$ are the state space discrete matrices:

$$x(t+1)=Ax(t)+Bu(t)\\y(t)=Cx(t)+Du(t)$$

Which in this case are obtained as:

```
b=[1/6 -1/3 0];
a=[1 1/6 -1/3];
[A,B,C,D]=tf2ss(b,a);
```

Hence, aside numerical issues, both methods gave the same results:

```
[h,t] = impz([1 -2],[6 1 -2]);
stem(t,h);

t=(0:23)';
h(1)=D*1;
for k=2:length(t)
    h(k,1)=C*A^(k-2)*B;
end
stem(t,h);
```

So the $t$=23th term on the $h(t)$ signal is:
$$h(23)=C A^{t-1} B|_{t=23}=C A^{22} B=-3.39702260269318e^{-05} $$

Though small, the $t$th term never vanishes, hence, transfer functions with denominator different than the identity vector, will always be an IIR.